# Building architecture from TDD written "modules"

Tags: ios, core-data, architecture

I'm fairly new to TDD and I'm writing my current project using TDD. trying to cover as much as possible with TDD as I go along and so far it's working out.

Each "module" in my project is self-contained. They can all be tested without relying on dependencies from other parts of the project and I can inject "mock" dependencies.

One of these is the `CoreData` `managedObjectContext` that is used to save and find items in the project.

So now I'm trying to put everything together and wondering how best to build it all.

For instance. I might have a view controller deep inside the app that has a service that saves something to `Core Data` and so this service "module" will need the `managedObjectContext` to do that.

How should I get it there?

Do I really need to pass the managed object context through a series of objects that don't actually require it? That seems like it breaks everything I'm working towards?

I could use a singleton but want to avoid it as it just causes pain (from previous experience).

How should I do this?

Comment: Coming from a Java perspective; I can only say: for Java, you would be looking towards frameworks that other **dependency injection**. Not injects required for testing; but at real runtime - a system that understands for example that knows how to instantiate such a CoreData object; to then make it available to "client code" that needs such an object. Then: it sounds a bit strange that you start thinking about such questions **after** creating all your modules. Of course, TDD is more about bottom up; but shouldn't you have done some level of "top-down" design **before** doing all the modules?!

Comment: @GhostCat ok, so instead of having to pass in the managed object context for Core Data I should have the "module" know how to instantiate it. The problem there being that the managed object context should be used throughout the app. Only one of them... which then makes me rethink that I should just use a singleton for the managed object context and in prod just get the singleton instance. Hmm...

Comment: @GhostCat RE the last question. I haven't yet done all the modules. I'm now thinking about the top-down design before I get too deep into the TDD of the modules that will require it. I don't want to get too far and then realise I need a whole different approach. :)

Comment: Of course, a **singleton** might be a pragmatic answer here. But the point of a **framework** is that it should also know about such things. A good DI frameworks can be told: here is that **one** object of that class; so make sure everybody who needs such an objects receives exactly **that** one.

Comment: @GhostCat but in order to do that do you not then need to make sure that there is some single instance of the entire framework passed around? Or accessed as a singleton. Which just defers the problem. If I tell the framework, "use this instance of this context" then I have to make sure that I am getting the same instance of that framework each time.

Comment: A) we are getting into discussion mode (which is what I somehow expected for such a almost too-broad question) and B) dont get too hang up on details. My main point was: *maybe* you want to look around if there are such frameworks for **your** target platform; and if so; you start looking what they **offer** to you - to decide if it would make sense for **you** to get into that business; or if you need another solution/technology/idea.

Comment: @GhostCat ok, thanks for the help. :)

Comment: You are very welcome. If you think my contribution really helped; maybe, consider upvoting one random answer of mine ;-)

Answer (score 1):

We are also writing our projects using TDD approach. Here are some details:

- we are using [VIPER architecture.](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/)
- Each module is a VIPER module.
- Dependency injection ([Swinject](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject)) for initialization of viper modules and adding dependencies.
- Daemons for handling application events on a per-module basis.
- Common service layer is responsible for talking to server and local storage.

We have internally developed [Cobra framework](https://github.com/locationlabs/Cobra) (using swinject) for bootstrap and routing, 
[Medusa](https://github.com/locationlabs/Medusa) for daemons. We have open sourced these projects but still need some documentation.

Here is the architectural diagram of our applications.

[image]

To answer your use case:

ViewController should not have instance of service. You should use interactor to interact
with service layer.
If you use [cobra](https://github.com/locationlabs/Cobra) and [medusa](https://github.com/locationlabs/Medusa) then you could define your assembly something like this:

```
// store assembly

container.register(StoreManager.self) { resolver in
   return StoreManager(...) 
}.inObjectScope(.Container) // for singleton


// service assembly

container.register(LoginServiceType.self) { resolver in
   return LoginService(store: resolver.resolve(StoreManager.self)!)
}

container.register(UserServiceType.self) { resolver in
   return USerService(store: resolver.resolve(StoreManager.self)!)
}


// Login Service

class LoginService {
   let store: StoreManager
   init(store: StoreManager) {
      self.store = store
  }

  func login() {
    store....()
  }
}


// User service

class UserService {
   let store: StoreManager
   init(store: StoreManager) {
      self.store = store
   }

   func fetchUserDetails(id: String) {
      store....()
   }
}
```

See the power of DI, now you don't need to worry about creating and passing of "store (any other object) instance". Basically you need to setup your assembly and you are all set.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks very much. I will investigate his pattern further. It actually looks something like the structure I have begun to develop anyway as a necessity of TDD. Without DI it's pretty much impossible to test individual units.